# XMLERR: Element '=").*?(?=")</regex' not closed while using lookaround

Tags: regular-expression, xml, pcre

I am trying to use lookaround element in PCRE2 regex for Wazuh tool, i need to match strings which are in double quotes and made the below regex however it looks its picking up "<" character and not closing the regex  element.

```
<regex type="pcre2">(?<=").*?(?=")</regex>
```

*ERROR: (1226): Error reading XML file 'etc/decoders/local_decoder.xml': XMLERR: Element '=").*?(?=")</regex' not closed. (line 33).*

I have tried to escape the < in (?***<***=") however it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to escape this in order to parse  element properly

Answer (score 1):

The PCRE2 regular expression syntax allows you to write assertions in different equivalent ways:

- `(?<=` is the same as either of these:

  - `(*plb:`
  - `(*positive_lookbehind:`
- `(?=` is the same as either of these:

  - `(*pla:`
  - `(*positive_lookahead:`

(This is from the PRCE2 library's [`pcre2pattern` manual](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC20).)

This means that you should be able to rewrite your regular expression without using characters that are special in XML (`<` in this case) as either the more expressive

```xml
<regex type="pcre2">(*positive_lookbehind:").*?(*positive_lookahead:")</regex>
```

or the terser

```xml
<regex type="pcre2">(*plb:").*?(*pla:")</regex>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<` is an XML metacharacter and has to be encdoded as `&lt;` or similar.

Also, `>` is `&gt;` and a literal `&` is `&amp;`

**However,** it appears that the tool you are using has a bug in this area, so you will have to figure out a workaround; see https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/14261

Comment: You mean <regex type="pcre2">(?&lt;=").*?(?=")</regex> ?

Comment: Yup, that's how you encode it. I'm not familiar with the tool you are using, though; maybe it has additional quirks or different internal conventions.

Comment: The original error seems to have gone now and i have a new one

        `ERROR: (1452): Syntax error on regex: '(?&lt;=").*?(?=")'`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the tool then. Are you forced to use XML or are there other options?

Comment: I am forced to use XML unfortunately, the requirement is to capture all data between set of double quotes .

Comment: i found something which replaced the regex pattern. Thank you for helping out ! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Comment: @Atul It's unclear how the StackOverflow Q/A is helpful as they are trying to match a double-quoted string _including the quotes_, while this question is using look-ahead and look-behind assertions to avoid matching the actual double quotes.

Comment: If the tool supports grouping, matching on `"([^"]*)"` and extracting group 1 is basically equivalent to the OP's attempt.